# Wired Settings Disappeared in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: network-manager, wired

Wired settings have disappeared from network settings. Only VPN option is still there. This is a new installation, it happened after installing nvidia drivers.

Following requirements from similar threads, my config is in the attached pictures.

[image: img_config]

I don't have any `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

```
File /etc/netplan/*.yaml:
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
```

Any idea of what can be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No driver attached

```
lsmod | grep r81
```

Remove

```
sudo modprobe -r <your_module_name>
```

Add

```
sudo modprobe <your_module_name>
```

If the module is not found. You can download the source code of the driver. Build for your version of the system.